# Read .txt filename, when filename contains dots

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to open a file name called 'x.1.1.1.txt'. But I'm getting problems because the several dots.

```
    f=open('x.1.1.1.txt','r')
```

When I use that function I get the message that the file name doesn't exists.

Thanks

Comment: is your file `x.1.1.1.txt` in the same folder with your python file?

Comment: Just verified that (as I suspected), Python 3 can open files with dots in with  no problem. Are you sure the script is in the same directory as the file you want to open, as @HaifengZhang asks?

Comment: not in the same directory as the file, but in the current directory, period. this filename is valid on most filesystems. Check current dir using `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: `.txt` makes me think of Windows. And if you save a text file in something like notepad and manually put `.txt` as extension when saving... the file actually ends in `.txt.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter where your file is located as long as the path you are providing is correct.

In the below example I specify the path to the file in a variable by itself. The example text file is located in my documents folder. The file's content is one example line of text.

try:

```
#if using windows filepath maybe C:\User\username\Documents
#if using mac filepath maybe /Users/username/Documents/
filepath = r'whole_path_to_file\x.1.1.1.1.1.txt'
o = open(filepath, 'r')
r = o.readlines()
print(r)
#output of example file nameed x.1.1.1.1.1.txt
['File content to read']
```

Hope that helps.